# Why is this Reg Exp not working

Tags: regex

I'm checking for 1.1 followed by 5 UPPER case characters.

```
\d{1}.{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{5}
```

E.g. both of these pass

```
1.1SMITH   

1.1SMITHA
```

I'd of thought `1.1SMITHA` should fail

Answer (score 2):

You should add two things to the regex.

- Escape the `.`. This is because `.` has special meaning in regex, that is it matches anything.
- Add anchors `^` and `$`.

  - `^` Anchors the regex at start of the string.
  - `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

  These anchors are important because it ensures that the substring matched by the regex is not followed( ensured by `$`) or preceeded ( ensured by `^`) by anything else.

The corrected regex can be written as

```
^\d\.\d[A-Z]{5}$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uE3kF8/2)

**Note :** You can skip the `{1}` part, as it is trivial.

Comment: Thank you. Reg Exp, something I do once a year if that !

Comment: @Rory You are welcome. Regex is nothing to be afraid of, its very easy but tricky thing :)